# Can't access Property inside Object node Swift

Tags: swift

I'm having problems to access custom property of a Node Object in swift. I'm gonna try to explain you.

I create a class that inherit from SkSpriteNode and I create a property that calls ( Has Gluten )

```
    init(foodName:  String, foodNote: String, foodImage: SKTexture, hasGluten: Bool) {
        self.foodNote = foodNote
        self.foodImage = foodImage
        self.hasGluten = hasGluten
        self.foodName = foodName

        super.init(texture: foodImage, color: UIColor.clear, size: CGSize(width: 40, height: 40))
        self.position = CGPoint(x: Int.random(in: 0..<355), y: 600)
        self.name = self.foodName

    }
```

Until here Ok, but when I add this node to the screen and I active touch Began I can't access the property HasGluten inside this class.. 
It says that I can acess just native properties like ( Name, position etc. )

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?)
{
    let touch:UITouch = touches.first!
    let positionInScene = touch.location(in: self)
    let touchedNode = self.atPoint(positionInScene)
    if touchedNode.hasGluten == true { callfunction() } else {call another function}

}
```

Here is the point where I want to access the property. but when I try to access the property HasGluten it doesn't give to me.

If someone could help I will be glad. Thanks

Comment: Could you please provide `func atPoint(_:)` code?

Comment: open func atPoint(_ p: CGPoint) -> SKNode
 It's inside the Class SKnode and I can't change anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to access your property you should cast node object to your custom type:

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?)
{
    let touch:UITouch = touches.first!
    let positionInScene = touch.location(in: self)
    guard let touchedNode = self.atPoint(positionInScene) as? CustomNode else { return }
    if touchedNode.hasGluten == true { callfunction() } else {call another function}

}
```

Instead `CustomNode` use correct class name.